# Lotus Notes Attachment attached inside body showing as gray icons

Tags: vba, excel, lotus-notes

Is there a way to get the attachment to appear with the correct icon when you add it through the macro inside body of email?. My issue is that when attaching a .pdf or .xlsx through my lotus notes macro it appears as a generic grey icon rather than the .pdf or .xlsx  icon. I tried only saving a draft of the email and it shows the .pdf or .xlsx  icon but when I switched my macro to display the email it shows a generic grey one.

```
Private Maildb As Object ' The Mail Database
Private Username As String ' The current users notes name
Private MailDbName As String ' The Current Users Notes mail database name
Private MailDoc As Object 'the mail document itself
Private AttachME As Object ' The attachement richtextfile object
Private session As Object ' The Notes Seesion
Private EmbedObj As Object ' The Embedded Object (attachment)
Private ws As Object 'Lotus Workspace

Private objProfile As Object
Private rtiSig As Object, rtitem As Object, rtiNew As Object
Private uiMemo As Object
Public strToArray() As String, strCCArray() As String, strBccArray() As String
'
Public Function f_SendNotesEmail(strAtask As String, strTo As String, strCC As String, strBcc As String, _
strObject As String, strBody As String, blnSaveIt As Boolean) As Boolean
    Dim strSignText As String, strMemoUNID As String
    Dim intSignOption As Integer

    Set session = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
    Set ws = CreateObject("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace")

    Username = session.Username
    MailDbName = Left$(Username, 1) & Right$(Username, (Len(Username) - InStr(1, Username, " "))) & ".nsf"

    On Error GoTo err_send

    Set Maildb = session.GETDATABASE("", MailDbName)
        If Maildb.IsOpen = False Then Maildb.OPENMAIL


    Set MailDoc = Maildb.CREATEDOCUMENT
        MailDoc.Form = "Memo"
        MailDoc.SendTo = strTo
        MailDoc.CopyTo = strCC
        'MailDoc.BlindCopyTo = strBcc
        MailDoc.subject = strObject
        MailDoc.SAVEMESSAGEONSEND = blnSaveIt

    Set objProfile = Maildb.GetProfileDocument("CalendarProfile")
        intSignOption = objProfile.GetItemValue("SignatureOption")(0)
        strSignText = objProfile.GetItemValue("Signature")(0)



    'Signature or not
    If intSignOption = 0 Then
        MailDoc.body = strBody
    Else
        'Insert a Signature
        Select Case intSignOption
            Case 1: 'Plain text Signature
                Set rtitem = MailDoc.CreateRichTextItem("Body")
                Call rtitem.AppendText(strBody)
                Call rtitem.AppendText(Chr(10)): Call rtitem.AppendText(Chr(10))
                Call rtitem.AppendText(strSignText)
            Case 2, 3: 'Document or Rich text
                'Open memo in ui
                Set uiMemo = ws.EditDocument(True, MailDoc)
                Call uiMemo.GotoField("Body")

                'Check if the signature is automatically inserted
                If objProfile.GetItemValue("EnableSignature")(0) <> 1 Then
                    If intSignOption = 2 Then
                        Call uiMemo.Import(f_strSignatureType(strSignText), strSignText)
                    Else
                        Call uiMemo.ImportItem(objProfile, "Signature_Rich")
                    End If
                End If

                Call uiMemo.GotoField("Body")

                'Save the mail doc
                strMemoUNID = uiMemo.Document.UniversalID
                uiMemo.Document.MailOptions = "0"
                Call uiMemo.Save
                uiMemo.Document.SaveOptions = "0"
                Call uiMemo.Close
                Set uiMemo = Nothing
                Set MailDoc = Nothing

                'Get the text and the signature
                Set MailDoc = Maildb.GetDocumentByUNID(strMemoUNID)
                Set rtiSig = MailDoc.GetFirstItem("Body")
                Set rtiNew = MailDoc.CreateRichTextItem("rtiTemp")
                Call rtiNew.AppendText(strBody)
                Call rtiNew.AppendText(Chr(10)): Call rtiNew.AppendText(Chr(10))
                    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xlsx")
                    Do While Len(strFile) > 0
                        '.AppendText ("hiui")
                        'Set AttachME = MailDoc.CreateRichTextItem("ATTACHMENT" & strFile) 'attaching as attachments not inside body
                        Call rtiNew.embedobject(1454, "", strPath & strFile, "ATTACHMENT")
                        '.AddNewLine (1)
                        strFile = Dir
                    Loop
                Call rtiNew.AppendRTItem(rtiSig)

                'Remove actual body to replace it with the new one
                Call MailDoc.RemoveItem("Body")
                Set rtitem = MailDoc.CreateRichTextItem("Body")
                Call rtitem.AppendRTItem(rtiNew)
        End Select
    End If

    MailDoc.Save False, False

    Set uiMemo = ws.EditDocument(True, MailDoc)

    f_SendNotesEmail = True

label_end:
    Set Maildb = Nothing
    Set MailDoc = Nothing
    Set AttachME = Nothing
    Set session = Nothing
    Set EmbedObj = Nothing
    Set rtitem = Nothing
    Set uiMemo = Nothing
    Set rtiSig = Nothing
    Set rtiNew = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
    Exit Function

err_send:
    f_SendNotesEmail = False
    GoTo label_end
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Showing the correct icon only works when done in the frontend. Whenever you use LotusScript to attach something in the backend, the symbol will always be the default one. There are workarounds with XML- Export / Import, but usually they are not feasible.

Comment: you can use rtlib (I'm author) or Midas (I think) to replace the default icon with any image with caption - looks good. But of course using a 3rd party software for a cosmetic problem usually cannot be justified.